# Tkinter Updating list from loaded Dataframe

Tags: python, tkinter

Building tkinter application that loads a selected .csv as a dataframe and prints the "Categories" of dataframe on second page listbox as selectable option.

Data from .csv in DataFrame Form

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['TNUAX', '1290 Diversified Bond A','Intermediate Core-Plus Bond'],
        ['ABSZX', 'AB Discovery Value Z','Small Value'],
        ['AUIAX', 'AB Equity Income A','Large Value']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Ticker', 'Fund Name','Category'])
df
```

Application Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk 
import pandas as pd


class MyApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')
        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class PageOne(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.make_widget()

    def make_widget(self):
        #Sections of Page/Canvas
        self.cvs = Canvas(self, width="500", height="60", background='#f0f0f0', bd=-2) #-2 to eliminate border
        self.cvs2 = Canvas(self, width="500", height="500", background="white", bd=-2)
        self.cvs3 = Canvas(self, width="500", height="60", background="#f0f0f0", bd=-2)
        
        #Fonts and sizes
        mainf = 'Arial'
        headsz = 20
        bodysz = 12
        
        def databrowser():
            root = tk.Tk()
            root.withdraw()
            data_f_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
            df = pd.read_csv(data_f_path)
            x = df.Category.unique().tolist()
            
        #Score Sort Header
        lbl=tk.Label(self.cvs2, text="Score Sort", background= 'white',fg='#529e3f', font=(mainf, headsz))
        lbl.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.01, relwidth=0.5, anchor='ne')
        #Select Data File (.csv) label
        datainlabel=Label(self.cvs2, text="Select Data File (.csv)", bg='white', fg='Black', font=(mainf,bodysz))
        datainlabel.place(relx=0.55, rely=0.55, relwidth=0.31, anchor='ne')
        #Select Data Input File Button
        InSbtn = Button(self.cvs2, text='Browse', font=(mainf, bodysz),command=databrowser)    #command=selected_item
        InSbtn.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.55, relwidth=0.15, anchor='ne')
        
        
        def func2():
            print('Load List Function Here?')
        
        
        #Next Page Button
        btnChange = Button(self.cvs3, text="Next", font=(mainf,bodysz),command=lambda: [self.controller.show_frame(PageTwo),func2()],
                           bg="white") #'#529e3f' #acdcea
        btnChange.place(relx=.775, rely=.15, width="80", height="40")
        
        def change_page(self):
            pass
        
         #Pack Sections 
        self.cvs.pack()
        self.cvs2.pack()
        self.cvs3.pack()
        
class PageTwo(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller  
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.make_widget()

    def make_widget(self):
        #Fonts and sizes
        mainf = 'Arial'
        headsz = 20
        bodysz = 12
        
        #Sections of Page
        self.cvs = Canvas(self, width="500", height="60", background='#f0f0f0', bd=-2) #-2 to eliminate border
        self.cvs2 = Canvas(self, width="500", height="500", background="white", bd=-2)
        self.cvs3 = Canvas(self, width="500", height="60", background="#f0f0f0", bd=-2)
        self.cvslist = Canvas(self, width="500", height="300", background="#acdcea", bd=-2)
        
        #Category Selection List
        yscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.cvslist)
        yscrollbar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
        #Create window label
        label = Label(self.cvslist,text = "Select Assset Categories :  ",font = (mainf, 13),bg='#acdcea', padx = 5, pady = 5)
        label.pack()
        # Create a listbox
        listbox = Listbox(self.cvslist, width=40, height=15, selectmode=MULTIPLE, font=(mainf,11),yscrollcommand = yscrollbar.set)
        #Expanse Option
        listbox.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10,expand = YES, fill = "both")

#Part that Loads Assets categories from csv in list 
        for each_item in range(len(x)):
            listbox.insert(END, x[each_item])
            listbox.itemconfig(each_item, bg = "white")

        #Back Page Button
        backbutt = tk.Button(self.cvs3, text='Back',font=('Arial',12), bg='white',command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        backbutt.place(relx=0.225, rely=0.15, anchor='ne', width="80", height="40")
       
        #Pack Sections 
        self.cvs.pack()
        self.cvs2.pack()
        self.cvslist.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.2, relwidth=0.5, anchor='ne')
        self.cvs3.pack()
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.title('Score Sort')
    app.mainloop()
```

**The Error:**
`name 'x' is not defined` from the part that loads this listbox

```
for each_item in range(len(x)):
     listbox.insert(END, x[each_item])
     listbox.itemconfig(each_item, bg = "white")
```

**My Attmept:**

Is to bind a command that loads the list when next button is pressed.

```
def func2():
            print('Load List Function Here?')
        
        #Next Page Button
        btnChange = Button(self.cvs3, text="Next", font=(mainf,bodysz),command=lambda: [self.controller.show_frame(PageTwo),func2()],
                           bg="white") #'#529e3f' #acdcea
        btnChange.place(relx=.775, rely=.15, width="80", height="40")
```

**Application with errant section #'out, to visually see app attempt:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk 
import pandas as pd


class MyApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')
        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class PageOne(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.make_widget()

    def make_widget(self):
        #Sections of Page/Canvas
        self.cvs = Canvas(self, width="500", height="60", background='#f0f0f0', bd=-2) #-2 to eliminate border
        self.cvs2 = Canvas(self, width="500", height="500", background="white", bd=-2)
        self.cvs3 = Canvas(self, width="500", height="60", background="#f0f0f0", bd=-2)
        
        #Fonts and sizes
        mainf = 'Arial'
        headsz = 20
        bodysz = 12
        
        def databrowser():
            root = tk.Tk()
            root.withdraw()
            data_f_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
            df = pd.read_csv(data_f_path)
            x = df.Category.unique().tolist()
            
        #Score Sort Header
        lbl=tk.Label(self.cvs2, text="Score Sort", background= 'white',fg='#529e3f', font=(mainf, headsz))
        lbl.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.01, relwidth=0.5, anchor='ne')
        #Select Data File (.csv) label
        datainlabel=Label(self.cvs2, text="Select Data File (.csv)", bg='white', fg='Black', font=(mainf,bodysz))
        datainlabel.place(relx=0.55, rely=0.55, relwidth=0.31, anchor='ne')
        #Select Data Input File Button
        InSbtn = Button(self.cvs2, text='Browse', font=(mainf, bodysz),command=databrowser)    #command=selected_item
        InSbtn.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.55, relwidth=0.15, anchor='ne')
        
        
        def func2():
            print('Load List Function Here?')
        
        #Next Page Button
        btnChange = Button(self.cvs3, text="Next", font=(mainf,bodysz),command=lambda: [self.controller.show_frame(PageTwo),func2()],
                           bg="white") #'#529e3f' #acdcea
        btnChange.place(relx=.775, rely=.15, width="80", height="40")
        
        def change_page(self):
            pass
        
         #Pack Sections 
        self.cvs.pack()
        self.cvs2.pack()
        self.cvs3.pack()
        
class PageTwo(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller  
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.make_widget()

    def make_widget(self):
        #Fonts and sizes
        mainf = 'Arial'
        headsz = 20
        bodysz = 12
        
        #Sections of Page
        self.cvs = Canvas(self, width="500", height="60", background='#f0f0f0', bd=-2) #-2 to eliminate border
        self.cvs2 = Canvas(self, width="500", height="500", background="white", bd=-2)
        self.cvs3 = Canvas(self, width="500", height="60", background="#f0f0f0", bd=-2)
        self.cvslist = Canvas(self, width="500", height="300", background="#acdcea", bd=-2)
        
        #Category Selection List
        yscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.cvslist)
        yscrollbar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
        #Create window label
        label = Label(self.cvslist,text = "Select Assset Categories :  ",font = (mainf, 13),bg='#acdcea', padx = 5, pady = 5)
        label.pack()
        # Create a listbox
        listbox = Listbox(self.cvslist, width=40, height=15, selectmode=MULTIPLE, font=(mainf,11),yscrollcommand = yscrollbar.set)
        #Expanse Option
        listbox.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10,expand = YES, fill = "both")

# #Part that Loads Assets categories from csv in list 
#         for each_item in range(len(x)):
#             listbox.insert(END, x[each_item])
#             listbox.itemconfig(each_item, bg = "white")

        #Back Page Button
        backbutt = tk.Button(self.cvs3, text='Back',font=('Arial',12), bg='white',command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        backbutt.place(relx=0.225, rely=0.15, anchor='ne', width="80", height="40")
       
        #Pack Sections 
        self.cvs.pack()
        self.cvs2.pack()
        self.cvslist.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.2, relwidth=0.5, anchor='ne')
        self.cvs3.pack()
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.title('Score Sort')
    app.mainloop()
```

**Understand this is alot of code and considerably complex from most stackoverflow questions. If anyone can suggest/recommend another platform where I can get hands on help that would be appreciated as well.**

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you how to make this work, but this is a really bad design.  Your second page is relying on data that was generated by the first page.  You need a sensible way to do that communication.  In the short term, if you add `global x` to your `databrowser` function, it will work.

At the very least, take `databrowser` out of `PageOne.make_widget` and make it a global function.  You'll still need the `global x` statement, but at least it makes it clear that it's not private data.